# how to change the path of a Firebase file in storage without uploading again?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a few hundred files in Firebase Storage which I need to relocate in a different path.

Is there a way to change the path of those files with Node or browser SDK without downloading and reuploading everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `gsutil` `mv` command ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mv)):

```
gsutil mv gs://bucket/path/to/file gs://bucket/new/path/to/file
```

It's also got options for recursive move (for doing a whole directory) using the `-r` flag:

```
gsutil mv -r gs://bucket/path/to/files gs://bucket/new/path/to/files
```

Comment: So what happens to the downloadURL / token after doing that?

Comment: I assume `mv` basically performs a `cp` and an `rm`, so the download URL would be invalidated.